# Metodo que retorna os quantos níveis tem uma Arvore Binaria

Tags: java, árvore-binária

Estou tentando implementar uma Arvore Binaria pela primeira vez mas estou com dificuldade no método que retorna a quantidade de níveis presentes na arvore depois de preenchida.

O método abaixo consegue percorrer perfeitamente todos os elementos presentes em cada nível da Arvore, o problema esta na parte de restringir quando o método deve guardar determinado nível com a variável "nivel++;". Desse jeito ele retorna a quantidade de elementos inseridos na Arvore.

Consegui implementar o seguinte código:

```
public int nivel(Node node){
    Node aux = raiz;
    int nivel = 0;
    if (aux == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arvore vazia.");
    Deque<Node> fila = new ArrayDeque<>();
    fila.add(node);

    while (!fila.isEmpty()) {
        Node atual = fila.removeFirst();
        if (atual.getNodeEsquerda() != null)     fila.add(atual.getNodeEsquerda());
        if (atual.getNodeDireita() != null) fila.add(atual.getNodeDireita());
        nivel++;
    }
    return nivel;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto altura com a quantidade de elementos são bem mais fáceis fazendo recursivamente utilizando um algoritmo *Depth First Search* (DFS), assim:

```
public int nivel(Node no){
    if (no == null) return 0;

    return (int)Math.max(nivel(no.getNodeEsquerda())+1, nivel(no.getNodeDireita())+1);
}
```

Utilizando *Breadth First Search* (BFS), que é o seu exemplo, estes ficam mais complexos e/ou extensos, apesar de terem outras propriedades, como por exemplo, percorrerem nível a nível em vez de em profundidade.

O seu código está a fazer o seguinte:

- Começa do 8 aumenta para nível 1 e empilha o 3 e o 10.
- Depois analisa o 3, aumenta o nível para 2 e empilha o 1 e o 6
- A seguir vai para o 10, e aumenta o nível para 3 empilhando o 13

Neste momento já não está certo pois o `3` e o `10` fazem parte ainda do mesmo nível. Assim o código irá aumentar para cada nó dando a quantidade de nós em vez da altura.

Uma solução que eu vejo é empilhar também o nível do nó para que cada nó considere o nível do nó pai para descobrir o seu, sendo o seu sempre o do pai mais 1. Para facilitar pode-se criar uma classe auxiliar que tenha uma referência para um `Node` e o seu `nivel`, modificando a `Queue` para utilizar esse tipo

Exemplo:

```
private class NodeNivel { //classe para ter No e Nivel
    public Node no;
    public int nivel;

    public NodeNivel(Node no, int nivel){
        this.no = no;
        this.nivel = nivel;
    }
}

public int nivel(){
    Node aux = raiz;
    int nivel = 0;
    if (aux == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arvore vazia.");
    Deque<NodeNivel> fila = new ArrayDeque<>(); //Agora Deque<NodeNivel>

    //cada vez que empilha leva nivel tambem,que é 1 para a raiz
    fila.add(new NodeNivel(aux, 1)); 

    while (!fila.isEmpty()) {
        NodeNivel atual = fila.removeFirst(); //Agora NodeNivel

        //estes ifs agora empilham NodeNivel aumentando o nivel em 1
        if (atual.no.getNodeEsquerda() != null) 
            fila.add(new NodeNivel(atual.no.getNodeEsquerda(), atual.nivel+1));
        if (atual.no.getNodeDireita() != null) 
            fila.add(new NodeNivel(atual.no.getNodeDireita(), atual.nivel+1));

        //verifica e atualiza o nivel maximo
        if (atual.nivel > nivel) 
            nivel = atual.nivel;
    }

    return nivel;
}
```